# How can i upload the file and form data in single api request in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

[admin.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxVfY.png)

[admin.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zatP.png)

this is code snippet i'm using for uploading the form and data. I'm able to post the form data to api but not the file.

admin.component.ts

```
private onFileChange(event: any) {
// let reader = new FileReader();
console.log("in file change method");
if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
  this.file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(event.target.files);

   }
```

}

```
private onSubmit(userform: any) {
    let _formData= new FormData();
    console.log(userform.value);
    userform.value.IdpMetadataFile = this.file;
    console.log(userform.IdpMetadataFile)
    console.log('formData', userform.value);
    this._adminServices.saveAdminConfig(userform.value).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.saveAdmin = true;
});
console.log("save admin " + this.saveAdmin);
```

}

....admin.component.html...

```
<div class="form-group">
        <p>Browse IDP Metadata file</p>
        <input type="file" name="IdpMetadataFile " id="IdpMetadataFile " (change)="onFileChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="ViewAdminConfigData.IdpMetadataFile "
            #idpMetaFileName="ngModel">
        <br>
```

Comment: please copy the code with an indentation of 4 space instead of using image, it allow us to copy/paste to edit for a solution

Comment: post the actual code so that others can create a reproducable plunker or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the file to the formdata object

```
onSubmit(){
   let _formData = new FormData();
   _formData.append('file', this.file);
   // call api to send the data
}
```